# Patching Wildfly using native or HTTP management API

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10, patch

I need to patch Wildfly10 using HTTP or native management API. I know how to do it with CLI using command

```
patch apply /home/user/patch.zip
```

but is it possible to apply patch using HTTP or native management API?
Also will that patch be applied to all servers in the targeted server-group?

Comment: Cant apply patch through management API's. currently can apply patch through CLI command and management console

Comment: This means you can: https://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/8.2.0.Final/core-service/patching/index.html

But I don't know how to do it. input-stream-index is the important part here I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. It can be done using native management API.
https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/master/patching/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/patching/tool/PatchOperationTarget.java#L384

It can also be done calling /management-upload url using multipart. One part of multipart is patch zip file, and the second part is json holding request for CLI command /core-service=patching:patch(input-stream-index=0)

you can view this behavior by patching server using admin console and looking in web browsers console network